# bootstrap testing - p value with subtraction and replication (Python)

Tags: p-value, bootstrap, permutation-test

`from std.disclaimer import "Dammit Jim, I'm a programmer, not a statistician."`

Edited to try to make the terminology more correct and the question more clear. *Mea culpa, mea befuddled.*

I am now in bootstrap and permutation land. (With apologies, DataCamp seems to assume that it's easy to understand how these differ. For someone new to both, they overlap considerably and I'm having trouble teasing apart the subtle differences in use case.)

The data is "medical charges". There are two types of data, A and B, (coded 'insured' or 'noninsured') in the dataset. The question of the exercises is: do the means differ for these types of records (samples?).

The null hypothesis would be, I assume, the means do not differ.

Because I have original data for both sets of samples, I have a choice of permutation test or bootstrap hypothesis test.

According to [DataCamp](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/statistical-thinking-in-python-part-2), I draw replicates from the original data sets  then look at the means of those new samples. If the original samples are essentially identical, the new means won't differ significantly from each other or from the mean I get before the replicates.

I've been asked if I'm talking about permutation or bootstrapping. I'm talking about both (or neither) because really I'm asking about this calculation of the p value, which DataCamp's uses for both:

```
p = np.sum(replicates_means >= empirical_diff_means) / len(replicates_means)
```

whether the replicates are created by permutation or bootstrapping.

Question 1: The >= confuses me. Why >=? Why not just get the mean of the replicates and see how close to 0 it is?

Question 2: If there is a difference between the samples (and, in this dataset, there is) and you do the subtraction in the "wrong" direction, you get negative differences.  i.e. the observed difference for the actual dataset is 7602 (or -7602 if you subtract in the other direction). As I naively discovered, I cannot use a >= test if the empirical value is a negative number! (400 may be less than 7600, but -400 is greater than -7600).

So, Q 2 is: do I check the empirical first, then either change the order of the subtraction or use `<=` in my p calculation
OR
should I run `abs` on my permuted and observed differences?

Best practice?

Comment: Presumably your data set consists of samples, not populations; otherwise you'd have no need for inference at all. What you should do depends on the null and alternative hypothesis, which are unstated in your question (and there's not enough context to tell for sure from datacamp's code, but presumably they're looking at a particular one-sided alternative). Your question requires clarification.

Comment: I presume the null hypothesis is "the means do not differ". I updated my question.

Comment: Your title is about the bootstrap, the text seems to be about permutation tests. Both are about resampling, but conceptually they are very different. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: @Michael M - Wellllll, that's a good question. Dare I say both? Or neither? I've edited my question. My question is about the >= in the p value calculation. The first time I did the exercise, I got a p value of 1. I was shocked and disbelieving. I dug. It turned out that I got 1 because I naively subtracted in the wrong order and -400 is a lot bigger than -7600 (but 400 is a lot smaller than 7600).  [I apologize for not understanding enough to use the proper terms and make the question clear to those who know much more than I do. The DataCamp "class" covers boh permutation & bootstrapping. :-(

Comment: @Vicki If you make your null a point null you're going to have to explain which direction or directions the alternative is in.